# how to get rid of running bash command every time

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Respected members whenever i build a package, every time i need to run `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` command. is there anyway to solve it ? while installing ROS i used this command `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` because in case of my friend he doesn't need to run everytime. he just did it in the beginning of ROS installation.
Please help.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284715/how-to-get-rid-of-running-bash-command-every-time/) by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add following environment variables to your `.bashrc` file

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/catkin_ws:/opt/ros/kinetic/share:/opt/ros/kinetic/stacks

export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/user/catkin_ws
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) on 2018-03-08**:
Additionally we have an alias `alias S='source ${HOME}/.bashrc'` to quickly source after building new packages, very useful